# loading Web Workers in bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, web-worker

I get my web worker working in a bookmarklet. The code resides in the same folder as the calling code, I dont explicitly load up the worker code as it is loaded using the `importScripts` function in the worker.js file.

I create the worker like so

```
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    }
```

then I call the worker like so

```
    worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'start', 'grabRate': grabRate});
```

which should call the function in my worker file

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log("worker message");
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'start':
      console.log("start from worker");
...
```

I don't see any debug messages in the console telling me that the 'message' has been called in the worker. I only load the code that calls the worker.js (in the bookmarklet loader function) since that is loaded by the `new Worker` function (If I also included the files in the loader function I could see the file but the function still isn't called). I cant see the worker files in the Chrome debug sources list or the other files loaded using the `importScripts` function.

Comment: The worker object does not seem null on what I see :[. It has a prototype, and also two properties onerror and onmessage.

Comment: where do you see a null object? From the output it seems you get the regular WebWorker object, but with no handlers attached right now

Comment: Sirko, Stranded Kid, your right, maybe I am a bit premature in thinking that the worker hasn't loaded yet, its probably something else related to the messages not working, I am debugging them now

Comment: @ejectamenta Bookmarklets run as if they were included on the page. Where is `worker.js`? For a moment, **suppose there is no bookmerklet at all**, and your bookmarklet code is inserted directly into a `<script>` on the page. Now the page you're working tries to reference the relative path `worker.js`. What file would it find? (i.e., take the URL of the page, delete everythig to the right of the last `/`, and replace it with `worker.js`. What comes up when you go to that URL?)

Comment: I did try adding a full path on the worker call, but got an error relating to the path being a https domain called from a http (so I kind of temporarily gave up on that idea), Now I have changed the domain to start "//mydomain.com/" to avoid the 'same origin' error and it finds the worker script fine. I am thinking though that it would be good if an error was reported by the browser that the file could not be found as the worker object looks the same in the debugger window (chrome) in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the bookmarklet loading the script in the context of the page on which it is running. As no error message was given by the debugger when the file was not found and the worker object appeared to be valid, the cause of the worker not functioning correctly wasn't obvious. To solve the problem the worker was loaded like this

```
 worker = new Worker('//path.to/worker.js');
```

(the // accounts for https/http domain)